# how to check where condition using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to check whether there are more than three teachers for a single subject. So  I am trying to select ids from the table for some conditions. the fact is that I have more than one or two classes and indices. so how to check for all classes and indices? I couldn't make it, how can it possible, I am not familiar with CodeIgniter

**controller**

```
$checkr =  $this->class_model->check($class_data,$subject);
```

**model**

```
function check($class_data,$subject)
  {
     foreach($class_data as $key => $value)
    {   
     $this->db->select('s_id');
     $this->db->from('table1');
     $this->db->where('type',2);
     $this->db->where('subject',$subject);
     $this->db->where('status',1); 

        $condition= array(
                    'class'    => $key,
                    'stream_index'     => $value 
                   );
        $this->db->where($condition);  
    }

   $rows = $this->db->get();
   $count= $rows->num_rows() ;
   return $count
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you..

```
function check($class_data,$subject){
    $class_teacher_count = array();
    foreach($class_data as $key => $value){   
        $this->db->select('s_id');
        $this->db->from('table1');
        $this->db->where('type',2);
        $this->db->where('subject',$subject);
        $this->db->where('status',1); 

        $this->db->where('class', $key);
        $this->db->where('stream_index',$value);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        $rows = $query->result();
        $count = count($rows);
        $class_teacher_count[$key] = $count;
    }
    return $class_teacher_count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function check($class_data,$subject){
    foreach($class_data as $key => $value){   
        $this->db->select('s_id');
        $conditions = array(
            'type' => 2,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'status' => 1,
            'class' => $key,
            'stream_index' => $value 
        );
        $teacher_count[$key] = $this->db->get_where('table1',$conditions)->num_rows();

    }
   return $teacher_count;
}
```